# Spring REST using Jackson - 400 bad request logging

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have spring REST set up fine using Jackson/JSON and everything works.

But I knowingly introduced an error in the structure of the message which resulted in a 400 - Bad Request. But there was no log output on the server. The error I would be expecting would be something like "Jackson unknown property exception" or whatever but it was caught and a 400 error was sent to the client, but no log of the exception on the server.

I don't want to debug everything on the server clearly, but I want Spring network level exceptions like this clearly labelled as error.

What is the correct way to switch this on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
    logger.warn("Returning HTTP 400 Bad Request", e);
}
```

Comment: Surely there is a more general approach to this? I would imagine the spring framework that throws these exceptions would have a log call before it throws the exception.

Comment: Spring does log them at DEBUG level as far as I can remember. Do take note that you can place this exception handler method in a superclass. Plus if you ever want to return error messages to the client (in addition to the status code), this is the way to go.

Comment: Another option would be to implement your own ExceptionHandlerResolver to do the logging at a more "general" level. Have a look at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-exceptionhandlers

Comment: I want to avoid writing any code. I'm new to the Spring framework but I'm going to just put debug level on for everything, and prune it down to what I need I think. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Jukka.. I was struggling to find the error in my JSON

Comment: @Jukka As far as for Spring4, the log level is TRACE.

Comment: @StealthRabbi in your `@Controller` annotated class. Also see David Welch's alternative approach below

Comment: -1 - random code stub without explaining anything about what you're trying to achieve. Where does this go? what does this do? pls explain

Comment: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped

Comment: Spring WebFlux users, handle `ServerWebInputException` instead.

Comment: I just added a debug breakpoint in my IDE on HttpMessageNotReadableException and inspect the error. Problem solved.

Answer (score 56):

In case anyone else stumbles on this issue, the following worked for me in Spring Boot 2 / Spring 5 and didn't require a code change.

I set the log level for `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation` to `DEBUG`. In my case I was seeing 400 responses in my client code but no logging on the server side (even with a custom error handler). After changing that log level the problem was obvious:

```
DEBUG 172.19.0.16  cs 2018-Jun-08 20:55:08.415 [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-9] - 
  method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor[line ?] - 
  Read [class java.lang.String] as "application/xml;charset=UTF-8" with [org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter@2de50ee4]
DEBUG 172.19.0.16  cs 2018-Jun-08 20:55:08.418 [https-jsse-nio-443-exec-9] - 
  method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod[line ?] - 
  Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'java.lang.String'
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: 
  Failed to convert value of type 'core.dto.RequestDTO' to required type 'java.lang.String'
```

Comment: This is the best option and should be accepted instead: you can keep the root log level to WARN while checking the request/reponse mapping/Jackson convertion details and failures, and no extra exception handler is required. Then you will not lose yourself upon the avalanche of log lines.

Comment: Could you please get me the configuration details to set it to DEBUG. How can I do it in log4j.properties.

Comment: There are plenty of examples online about configuring log4j using properties file. You can try this article: https://www.journaldev.com/10698/log4j-properties-file-example. Basically you'll need something like `log4j.logger.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation=DEBUG, console` but it will depend on what appenders you have defined.

Comment: With Spring Boot you can just add -Ddebug to your VM options.

Comment: Or with SpringBoot just add an environment variable (e.g. for Kubernetes/OpenShift directly to the ConfigMap): LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK_WEB_SERVLET_MVC_METHOD_ANNOTATION: DEBUG

Comment: Can also do this programmatically, if you wanted to toggle it on and off when the instance is running  `((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()).getLogger("org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation").setLevel(Level.DEBUG)`

Answer (score 48):

Building on @Jukka's answer, you can enable this globally for all controllers using `@ControllerAdvice` (introduced in Spring 3.2). It does require a little code on your end, but in my experience you usually end up needing a global error handling configuration anyways and this allows you to set breakpoints / easily inspect the problems.

An example of this is below:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerConfig {

    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void handle(HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
        log.warn("Returning HTTP 400 Bad Request", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful. But be sure to place your ControllerAdvice inside a package scanned by Spring: my first attempt failed because I placed it - being a rather generic approach - in another, more general package than my controller and so it has not been heeded by Spring.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore because Spring has an `@ExceptionHandler` annotation for `HttpMessageNotReadableException` in its `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler#handleException` method now.  When I add the above to my code, I get this error:  `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException]` because my exception mapper is conflicting with Spring's.

Comment: Here's the documentation to Spring's exception handler that I mentioned above:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html#handleException-java.lang.Exception-org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest-

Comment: Spring WebFlux users, handle `ServerWebInputException` instead.

Comment: `Ambiguous @ExceptionHandler method mapped for [class org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException` I hate that part of spring, and the fact that they hide errors, Big anti pattern.

Answer (score 13):

You can set the `log` level to debug for this property in `application.properties`.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web= DEBUG
```

Comment: this also works with a reactive stack (webflux)

Comment: I did this and it did log the values of the DTO object but did not provide which property had trouble serializing

Comment: Thanks. This actually showed the error in the terminal.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the problem was in my `@ControllerAdvice`-annoted class, which extended `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`. As I got that handler code from some random tutorial about custom exception handling, I didn't bother to check what that superclass was doing (my custom exception handling worked just fine).

The problem is `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleException()` handles `MethodArgumentNotValidException` along with other Spring MVC exceptions, delegating handling logic to specific handle- methods. As I did not provide an implementation for any of such methods (in this case `handleMethodArgumentNotValid()`) to return my own response body, I ended up with the default implementation that returns a response with null body :).

### Solution

Override the methods you need or don't extend that class at all.

Check [ResponseEntityExceptionHandler docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html) for the list of hanler- methods implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is mandatory to extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler. You can create multiple handler methods in ControllerAdvice class annotated with ExceptionHandler and you can return any kind of response. Please check below link for more details and code example.
https://www.thetechnojournals.com/2019/11/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-rest.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are extending `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`, you can override `handleExceptionInternal()` in order to have any exception logged:

```
    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleExceptionInternal(Exception ex, Object body, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        log.error("There was an error handling request", ex);
        return super.handleExceptionInternal(ex, body, headers, status, request);
    }
```