# How to encode square brackets in spring url?

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, backbone.js

I have a path variable which has square brackets in spring url.But i am getting bad reuqest for the same. I am encoding the url in backbone framework using encodeUriComponent. But still even after url being encoded correctly i am getting bad request.

Comment: Post an example, and desired result.

Comment: Suppose if i have a spring url :- @RequestMapping(value = "/Entity/Object/{id}/information", method = RequestMethod.GET) then if i send {id} as [] from UI then it gives me an error as badrequest.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326976/spring-rest-using-jackson-400-bad-request-logging this link is giving some clue but still breakpoint is not being hit after trying this thing too.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was because of backward slash in the path variable and it needs a double encoding for it to get encoded correctly.