# How do I print the json that errors when sent to a Spring @RestController?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm getting this error in my log:

```
2016-04-06 09:22:24,623 W DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@540c46e3; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@540c46e3; line: 1, column: 1]
```

This is difficult to debug because it doesn't tell me what JSON is being sent to the endpoint.  How do I print out the json that it's trying to deserialize?

We are using tomcat as a web container

Comment: Jackson uses its streaming API for parsing the JSON, it won't consume all of it to print it. Add a valve (depends on your servlet container) that dumps the HTTP request or a `Filter`/`Interceptor` that does the same. You'll have to be careful and allow the `InputStream` to be consumed twice.

Comment: another option is implement a second handler that takes the @RequestBody and dumps it to a log.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326976/spring-rest-using-jackson-400-bad-request-logging  One of the answers suggests that you implement an @ExceptionHandler to handle and dump the HttpMessageNotReadableException.