# REST API call returning 400 even if code is not having error

Tags: java, spring-boot

I made one rest API that is manipulating a file and then uploading the file to third party and then it will have two database operations. First one is select and the second one is insert.

In few cases, I am getting 200 but in some cases I am getting 400. Now, when I am getting 400, the control is only coming till select method and there is no error in that method.

[image]

So, it looks like request is getting timeout or something.

Can anyone please suggest the proper way to do it? Where should I change the timeout?

**Success logs**-

```
[2019-04-11 10:09:26] [T] [http-nio-10.0.0.219-7000-exec-11] [Controller]  DOCUMENT UPLOADED IN Folder
[2019-04-11 10:09:26] [T] [http-nio-10.0.0.219-7000-exec-11] [Controller] Checking if transition is valid from new NEW status -  initiated
[2019-04-11 10:09:26] [T] [http-nio-10.0.0.219-7000-exec-11] [Controller] CALLING FUNCTION TO SAVE RESPONSE IN DIGIO_RESPONSES IN DB
[2019-04-11 10:10:11] [T] [http-nio-10.0.0.219-7000-exec-14] [Controller] [LFT] [userId = 12] POST 200 /storage/upload
```

**FAILURE logs**-

```
[2019-04-11 10:10:11] [T] [http-nio-10.0.0.219-7000-exec-14] [Controller]  DOCUMENT UPLOADED IN Folder
[2019-04-11 10:10:11] [T] [http-nio-10.0.0.219-7000-exec-14] [Controller] Checking if transition is valid from new NEW status -  initiated
[2019-04-11 10:10:11] [T] [http-nio-10.0.0.219-7000-exec-14] [Controller] [LFT] [userId = 12] POST 400 /storage/upload
```

Answer (score 1):

```
No issue with timeout
```

> **400 Bad Request** The server cannot or will not process the request due
>   to an apparent client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, size too
>   large, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
>
> **504 Gateway Timeout** The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and
>   did not receive a timely response from the upstream server.

`400` means that the request was malformed. In other words, the data stream sent by the client to the server didn't follow the rules.

In the case of a REST API with a JSON payload, you may get 400 when the JSON is invalid in some way according to the API specification for the service.

---

```
Good Practice:
```

If the request is Successful, then you may get `2xx` code (`3xx` for redirect). If there is an Internal Logic Error on a Server, then return `5xx`. If there is anything wrong in a Client Request, then you may get `4xx` code.

Comment: I will take care of it from now on

Answer (score 0):

This is a bad request:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

From the above page:

> it indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
>
> The client should not repeat this request without modification.

It's not a timeout.  You need to post more information, and look in your web server logs to see why the request is bad, it could be a number of things.

Comment: I have updated the logs that I am getting. As you can see for success, one extra call for db is happening but for failure case, we are getting 400 before the call itself.

Answer (score 0):

Trouble-shooting 400 response code in Spring is the bane of my existence. It amazes me how easily exceptions are swallowed or logged at DEBUG.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53770263/657224). Enabling DEBUG logging for particular Spring packages has helped me solve these type of silent failures on numerous occasions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.