# Spring rest-service: PUT Method returning HTTP 400

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, put, spring-rest

I have the following rest service api to update a "friends" dataset:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Friends> updateFriendship(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
                                                    @Valid @RequestBody Friends friendsDto)
            throws ResourceNotFoundException, InvalidDataException {
        Friends updatedLecture = businessLogicFriends.update(id, friendsDto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedLecture);
    }
```

When i try to put the updated object "friends" by using the Spring restTemplate like this:

```
public void updateFriends(Friends friends) {
        restTemplate.put(this.friendsServiceEndpoint+ "/" +friends.getId_friend().toString(), friends);
    }
```

i get back a HTTP 400 BadRequest error.

I dont know why this is happening. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you are passing valid friends object when using rest Template put method meaning the value of the fields in Friends class are valid as you have a @Valid annotation on request body

Comment: You can try to get more information by increasing the log level for the controller or by instructing Spring to include the error messages in the response body.

Comment: For logging reasons for errors in controllers, have a look at the Spring Boot property "logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG"

For details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53770263/2161004 and  https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are passing valid friends object when using rest Template put method meaning the value of the fields in Friends class are valid as you have a @Valid annotation on request body