# Springboot @RequestBody fails to deserialize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

I have below structure of DTO.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Parent{
  String parendId; 
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Child1 extends Parent{
  String childId;
  String childName;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class Child2 extends Parent{
  String childId;
  String childName;
  String school;
}
```

My RequestBody request class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class GeneralRequest{
 Child1 child1;
 Child2 child2;
```

}

My Springboot controller

```
@RestController
```

class FamilyController{

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String submit(@RequestBody GeneralRequest generalRequest){

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * 
     * some code
     * 
     * 
     * 
     */
    return something;

}
```

}

### Request json:

```
{
"child1":{
    "parentId" : "P1",
    "childId":"C1",
    "childName":"C1++"
},
"child2":{
    "parentId" : "P1",
    "childId":"C2",
    "childName":"C2++",
    "school":"schoolname"
}
```

}

**When I am hitting the controller it is giving me 400 bad error.
Can someone tell me what is wrong with this.**

I am using postman to invoke the API

Comment: Missing colon after "child1" and "child2"

Comment: Your requested 'json' is not in JSON format.

Comment: Do you have setters in DTO?

Comment: Hi menteith Yes I am using lombok and it has @Data annotation

Comment: You may add logging to see what's wrong with you request body. Here's how to do it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70591947/2657875

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is related to deserialization of the JSON request into your `GeneralRequest` object. Spring Boot's default JSON deserialization may not be able to determine which child class (`Child1` or `Child2`) to instantiate based on the JSON structure you provided. To fix this issue, you can use Jackson's `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation to specify the subtype information in your JSON payload.

Here's how you can modify your DTO classes and request JSON:

1. Update your `Parent` class to include `@JsonTypeInfo` annotation and `@JsonSubTypes` annotation to specify the subtypes.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
  property = "type"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child1.class, name = "child1"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child2.class, name = "child2")
})
class Parent {
  String parendId;
}
```

2. Update your `GeneralRequest` class to include a `type` property indicating the child class.

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
class GeneralRequest {
  Parent child1;
  Parent child2;
}
```

3. Modify your JSON request to include the `type` property for each child.

```json
{
  "child1": {
    "type": "child1",
    "parentId": "P1",
    "childId": "C1",
    "childName": "C1++"
  },
  "child2": {
    "type": "child2",
    "parentId": "P1",
    "childId": "C2",
    "childName": "C2++",
    "school": "schoolname"
  }
}
```

With these changes, Jackson will be able to determine the correct subtype to instantiate based on the `type` property in the JSON request, and the deserialization should work as expected in your Spring Boot controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try to fix this issue this way:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child1.class, name = "child1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Child2.class, name = "child2")
})
class Parent {
    String parentId;
}
```

It is Jackson annotations `@JsonTypeInfo` and `@JsonSubTypes` which you should use on your parent class.

Comment: Hey @Zufur Sunagatov actually that was typo I have corrected the question. Even though I pass the correct json it is giving 400 bad request,

Comment: @Pravin, let me check it again

Comment: @Pravin try to use my updated answer

Comment: Hi @Zufur let me try that

Comment: @Pravin 
You can add logging to see what's wrong with you request body. 

logging.level.org.springframework.web= DEBUG

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255277/discussion-between-zufar-sunagatov-and-pravin).

Comment: 400 Usually indicates an issue on the client side, not on the server side, share the details on how you're calling it.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your model or payload, you can verify this by creating a quick test that de-serializes the json into a GeneralRequest.

```
String serializedGeneralRequest = "{\n" +
        "\"child1\":{\n" +
        "    \"parentId\" : \"P1\",\n" +
        "    \"childId\":\"C1\",\n" +
        "    \"childName\":\"C1++\"\n" +
        "},\n" +
        "\"child2\":{\n" +
        "    \"parentId\" : \"P1\",\n" +
        "    \"childId\":\"C2\",\n" +
        "    \"childName\":\"C2++\",\n" +
        "    \"school\":\"schoolname\"\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "}";

GeneralRequest generalRequest = new ObjectMapper().readerFor(GeneralRequest.class).readValue(serializedGeneralRequest);
```

Given that 400s are normally due to issues with the client, update your question to include details about how you're calling it, like the curl command would be helpful.

Also, I would suggest that you take some time to read up on composition vs. inheritance because from looking at your logic, I think you have them confused.  According to your model, a Child IS A Parent (no exceptions).  You probably want your model to more accurately reflect that a Child HAS A Parent, and that a Parent has Children.  In other words, model this relationship with composition, not with inheritance.